# Google Maps JavaScript API v3 : Place Autocomplete : Weird characters in suggestions

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I am using place autocomplete api for my website and using Mexico as country restriction. But whenever i am entering 1 as search then it is giving some suggestions like 10ኛው-ኪኒኤንቶስ, México, 10ኛው-ካን, México etc...

To reproduce, go to the
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-hotelsearch
Select Mexico in country select and enter 1 in search box.

These suggestions have special characters. Please let me know that is it expected or is it a bug? If it is expected then please let me know what is the purpose of having these characters in suggestions.

Thanks,
Manoj Varma

Comment: I don't see any special characters in Chrome.  What browser?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug. I don't even know what language this is.

I reported it here: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7547&thanks=7547&ts=1421757773

You can subscribe to the issue and you will be notified if anything is done about it.

Comment: Hi MrUpsidown, I have already posted this to Google. Here is the link: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7544&thanks=7544&ts=1421747966. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You posted it twice. [#7543](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7543) and [#7544](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7544). Maybe they will merge the 3 issues. When you report an issue that you want to discuss here, then it's a good idea to paste a link to the issue in your question, and a link to your question in the bug report.